# Symfony 4 An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I am trying to create a database in symfony 4 using `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` command in terminal, but I keep getting the same 3 errors:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:
                                                                              
  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
                                                                              

In PDOConnection.php line 31:
                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
                                             

In PDOConnection.php line 27:
                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

There are a few similar problems which seem to be solved by changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost in the .env file DATABASE_URL line, but none of these solutions fix the problem. Changing to localhost for me gives the same error but 'no such file or directory' instead of 'connection refused'.

Comment: It looks like your connection string is wrong, e.g. misspelled credentials, wrong port info, etc.. Can you connect with a 3rd party tool like, e.g. the [Database Tool Window in PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/database-tool-window.html)? How did you set up your database?

Comment: The database is not set up yet. That's what I was trying to achieve. The connection string is automatically generated in symfony so should be right?

Comment: you need a running (possibly empty) database, to which symfony can connect. *Symfony doesn't really create a database*, it can only connect to one and fill it with tables and stuff. And for that you need to provide it with connection credentials.

Comment: Connection refused means the specified address wasn't listening on the given port.   This is distinct from permission error.   No such file or directory probably implies a unix domain socket instead (mysql uses unix socket by default for `localhost`, but 127.0.0.1 will always be tcp/ip).  Either way,  seems like maybe mysql server isn't running,  or if it is,  nonstandard port / socket path will need to be configured in your code.

Comment: What Jakumi says. `bin/console doctrine:database:create` will create a database (instance) on your database server. The database server must be running and Symfony must be able to connect to it. You might want to switch the connection to a local file based database called sqlite for your first development steps: `DATABASE_URL: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"`

Comment: Oh I see, I am new to this as you can probably tell. Thank you for your help.